# Draw a vertical line on seaborn jointplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to draw a vertical line on a Seaborn Joint Plot and either get two plots, or an error stating ax is not iterable.   The logic is as follows:

```
a4_dims = (12, 4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
ax.set_xlim(-.75, 1.25)
ax.set_ylim(-.75,1.25)
plt.axvline(0)
sns.jointplot(x='1_3Movement',y='1_2Movement',data=dfm,kind='kde', xlim=(-.75, 1.25), ylim=(-.75,1.25))
```

and this is what I get.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seaborn's [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) creates its own figure and 3 axes. `jointplot` returns a `JointGrid` object. You can grab the individual axes via `.ax_joint`, `.ax_marg_x` and `.ax_marg_y`. To draw a line onto the contour plot part, use `.ax_joint`.

The jointplot is always a quadratic figure. The figsize can be set via `height=` (the width will be equal).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

kdeplot = sns.jointplot(x=np.random.normal(0.25, 0.5, 10), y=np.random.normal(0.25, 0.5, 10),
                          kind='kde', xlim=(-.75, 1.25), ylim=(-.75, 1.25), height=4)
# draw a vertical line on the joint plot, optionally also on the x margin plot
for ax in (kdeplot.ax_joint, kdeplot.ax_marg_x):
    ax.axvline(0, color='crimson', ls='--', lw=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]